# how can I leave blank lines between outputs of echo?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to run a bash script and leave spaces between each echo. Currently I do it this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo
echo 'foo'
echo
echo 'bar'
```

output

```
foo

bar
```

But this doesn't look very professional. I've tried it like this, but the space on the first line is double

```
echo -e '\n'
echo -e 'foo\n'
echo -e 'bar\n'
```

To fix fist line i put:

```
echo -e ''
```

Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want formatted output, you might have better luck with `printf`:

```
$ printf "\n%s\n\n%s\n" "foo" "bar"

foo

bar
$
```

I tend to think of it like the C `printf` function, but as @freddy suggested in a comment below, you can simplify that to:

```
$ printf "\n%s\n" "foo" "bar"

foo

bar
```

From `man zshbuiltins` (but I think this is common across implementations):

> ```
> If arguments remain unused after formatting, the format string
> is reused until all arguments have been consumed.
> ```

Comment: Shorter and easier to handle: `printf '\n%s\n' 'foo' 'bar'`

Comment: @Freddy good call -- I updated the answer to include your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

?

```
echo -e "\nfoo"
echo -e "\nbar"
```

Comment: thanks for fix my commands. I had not seen your answer, but would have selected it

Answer (score 0):

```
#function out() {
#    echo
#    echo $*
#}

# or

function out() {
    echo -e '\n'"$*"
}

out foo
out bar
```

Consider also combibing this answer with other answers relating to `printf`.